# Rails 4; How to Display an RSS Feed on HTML View?

Tags: html, ruby-on-rails, ruby, rss

I'm building a personal website using Ruby with Rails 4.

I'm attempting to scrape Medium.com and have my Medium articles show up on my page. It's almost working, they *are* displaying on my page how I would want them, but it also displays the entire RSS code underneath my blog posts. I can't figure out how to get this data dump off my view.

What can I do to change this?

Here is my code on the controller:

```
def blog
    require 'rubygems'
    require 'rss'
    require 'open-uri'

    @rss = RSS::Parser.parse('https://medium.com/feed/@AlextheYounger/')
end
```

Here is the code on my HTML view:

```
    <%= @rss.items.each do |item|%>
    <div class="row">
      <div id="article-div" class="col-xs-8">
        <div class= "well well-lg">
          <div class= "article-title">
            <p><%="#{item.title}"%></p>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
   <% end %>
```

Again, it actually does display my blog posts, it just does so with a massive data dump included. How do I get rid of this massive data dump?

Comment: change the `<%= @rss %>` to `<% @rss %>` so ERB doesn't render the `@rss`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue is that `<%=` differs from `<%`

The equals sign tells rails "spit out the result of the current ruby statement onto the screen into your html"... in this case, you are spitting out the result of the ruby-code: `@rss.items.each`... which happens to return the value of `@rss.items` (which is all of your rss feed).

For ruby-statements that don't need to output to the screen (like this), just change to using the non-equals-sign version: `<%` and you should be good to go.

Comment: That did it!! Thank you so much!!